# Salvar tts como arquivo de audio

Tags: java, android, app

Como posso gerar um arquivo de áudio a partir de um `TexttoSpeech` para compartilhar com outros serviços (**sms**, **whats**, **messenger**, **...**)?

Criei essa função para compartilhar

```
private void shareAudio() 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_SEND );
    intent.setType("audio/3gpp");
    startActivity( intent );
}
```

mas não faço ideia de como "tratar" o tts antes, alguma ideia?

Answer (score 0):

#### Alternativa 1

A biblioteca [**TextToSpeech**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) não suporta gravação do áudio, no entanto, pode tentar entrar em modo de gravação enquanto você fala através da classe [**MediaRecorde**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html):

```
MediaRecorder minhaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
```

Para iniciar uma gravação, é necessário usar os métodos `prepare()` e `start()`:

```
minhaRecorder.prepare();
minhaRecorder.start();
```

> Um TextToSpeech só pode ser usada para sintetizar o texto.

É importante ressaltar que nem todas as línguas são suportadas pela *API TextToSpeech*. Por isso é interessante executar o método [`isLanguageAvailable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#isLanguageAvailable(java.util.Locale)) para ver se você pode ou não utilizar determinado idioma nessa estrutura.

#### Alternativa 2

Essa seria uma outra alternativa, caso você não queria utilizar a voz do usuário. Você pode usar o Google Tradutor para ler o texto que foi capiturado pela voz e converter em MP3. Aí seu trabalho seria salvar esse MP3 dentro de sua aplicação, porém só funcionaria se você estiver com Internet, pois acessaria em tempo real o Google Tradutor. Veja o link abaixo utilizando a palavra **"teste"**.

http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&total=1&idx=0&textlen=32&client=tw-ob&q=Teste&tl=Pt

Detalhes

- [Audio Capture](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html)
- [An introduction to Text-To-Speech in Android](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html)

Comment: Mas você diz capturar (a partir do microfone) o som do tts? Não há como transformar o tts em uma string ou algo do tipo, e a partir dessa string gerar um mp3 com a voz do tts o qual seja possível compartilhar?

Comment: @pokemon_cwb eu digo capturar a partir do microfone o som da voz da pessoa que está falando utilizando o tts. Mas a questão de transformar string em voz, daria também para para usar api do o google tradutor.

Comment: @pokemon_cwb editei a resposta colocando o link do google tradutor como alterativa 2